# Waiting on dissimilar input channels

Tags: python-3.x, pika

I'm trying to write a program that listens on a RabbitMQ queue and display statistics using curses.

I would like to listen for keystrokes (to quit or change the display) and queue messages at the same time, reacting appropriately as soon as they arrive. I might also want to add another dissimilar input down the line, such as a socket.

What is the simplest way to accomplish something like this in Python3? selectors? Threads? asyncio?

There seems to be a plethora of options, and yet, it's never clear to me that any of them will meet my use case.